# Removing "Validation failed" message from Exception return message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model Account :

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :msisdn

  validates_uniqueness_of :msisdn, :on => :create, 
    :message => "User Already Registered ."
end
```

And I have a controller which try to create an account :

```
begin
  account = Account.create!(:msisdn => user)   
rescue Exception => e
  $LOG.error "Account #{user} : --> #{e.message}"  
end
```

Now the e.message always return : **Validation failed: Msisdn User Already Registered**, how am I supposed just to get just the message alone like **User Already Registered**. please note that I'm not using views at all, I want to use it from controller, and I'm using Rails 3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When valid? is called on any model (which happens from create/save/update_attributes) it populates an errors object on the model. <s>Of course if you use a bang method (create!) then the assignment will never happen, so use a non bang method instead.</s> See 3rd code snippet.

```
account = Account.new(:msisdn => user)
unless account.save #
  # account.errors will be populated with errors
  puts account.errors[:msisdn] # => ['User Already Registered']
end
```

Alternative using a bang method

```
account = Account.new(:msisdn => user)
begin
  account.save!
rescue Exception
  puts account.errors[:msisdn]
end
```

Edit:

Another alternative after looking at the rails api docs is to get the record from the exception as it stores a copy. This makes my original statement false.

[ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html)
([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0034b7822d6132f5945b0514a5391d18e52aa4b6/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L12-L19))

```
begin
  account = Account.create!(:msisdn => user)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  puts e.record.errors[:msisdn] # => ['User Already Registered']
end
```

Answer (score 15):

Add two things to "config/locale/en.yml":

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        record_invalid: "%{errors}"
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

(or corresponding translation files for whichever languages you happen to support).

*Note: this was tested in rails 5, but a quick scan of rails 3 docs makes me think it'll work there too.*

Comment: God thank you. This is the correct answer for application level configuration with exception handling. Works in Rails 5.2.2. Quick note, if anyone wants to include the attribute in question, change the format to `format: "%{attribute} %{message}"`